# Mandatory Helper class for module admin panel settings

Tags: magento-1.7, module, configuration, helper, system.xml

Why its mandatory to define a helper class for adding configuration to the admin panel ?

i.e: I want to add some admin panel configuration to my module, So that when a user installed my module he/she can change some parameters via System >> Configuration >> MyTestModule.

So I need to create a system.xml and add my settings there, which is ok.

But why I need to create an empty helper class to make it work ?

```
<global>
        <helpers>
            <test>
                <class>Namespace_Test_Helper</class>
            </test>
        </helpers>
</global>
```

If I don't define the helper class it'll throw an error:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

The *useless* class I'm talking about is in Data.php and is something like this:

```
class Namespace_Test_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Isn't it some kind of stupid to create an empty class if I never using it ? What's the point ? Its completely useless to create an empty Helper class in my opinion. What I missed here ? Why its mandatory? Why it throws error when we don't create it. What's the use of helper class in here ?

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have (a fragment) of your `system.xml`, but probably you have something like `translate="label"` somewhere and `module="your_module"`.

Magento will load the `your_module` `Data` helper to translate the labels.

If you would set `module="core"` then your module doesn't have to have a helper to translate the labels as it will use the `core` `Data` helper to translate.

Answer (score 2):

Magento uses the helper to translate strings inside the module configuration. The file does not empty, it inherits all parent methods.

Comment: Of course the Helper class is empty itself, it just inherits the parent class, but its empty by itself. So why we need to create a useless class ? Magento should do it automatically if nothing defined. Is it a fundamental design issue or there is a purpose that I don't aware of ? If so, what is the purpose of creating an empty class that inherits another class?

Comment: Translations belong to a module. It is useless if you don't use your module to translate anything, but probably you are using it to translate a label in a XML file.